# Каким образом можно скопировать список от 0 до n?

Tags: python, список

```
f = [15, 3, 1, 3, 27]
```

В цикле я должен передавать списки представлены ниже

```
[15]
[15, 3]
[15, 3, 1]
[15, 3, 1, 3]
[15, 3, 1, 3, 27]
```

Comment: Привет! Пожалуйста, сформулируйте вопрос более развернуто, желательно предоставив минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода того, что у вас не получается

Answer (score 5):

Нужно сделать перебор индексов и использовать срезы

Пример:

```
f = [15, 3, 1, 3, 27]
for i in range(len(f)):
    print(f[:i+1])
```

Результат:

```
[15]
[15, 3]
[15, 3, 1]
[15, 3, 1, 3]
[15, 3, 1, 3, 27]
```